# Does a trirectangular tetrahedron exist with all face areas odd integers?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

By [De Gua's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem) we know the areas of the three right angle faces $a,b,c$ and the base $d$ are related by an extension of the Pythagorean Theorem to [trirectangular tetrahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trirectangular_tetrahedron):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$$

Is it possible to have all the face areas be odd integers? A quick check of all integers less than 1000 does not turn up any examples. In fact, there seem to be only two cases by examining solutions. Either (1) a triangular tetrahedron must have two right angle faces with even area and one right angle face and base with odd area or (2) all faces have even area.

Comment: I wonder whether this has something to do with an Euler brick.

Comment: @Peter I am guessing it can be shown that two faces must be even in a similar fashion to the argument that one side of a [Pythagorean triple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html) must be even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the face areas, i.e., $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, can't all be odd integers in

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is because $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ for all odd integers $n$. Thus, the left side would be congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, but the right side would be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: This explains also why the only two cases which are possible are one odd face and odd base or all even face areas.